# Search under condition in one column if a value in another column is unique, and write the results in a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 70k rows and two columns. Col1 contains bill of materials name and customer, Col2 contains a part number (which is a part of the BOM).

```
         Col1  Col2
0  TUR, Cust1  1001
1  GAR, Cust2  1001
2  FOR, Cust3  1001
3  ERB, Cust1  1002
4  PNR, Cust1  1002
5  DUL, Cust2  1003
6  COC, Cust3  1003
7  ETM, Cust1  1004
8  ROW, Cust3  1005
9  HON, Cust3  1005
```

When searching for Cust1, I want to see in column3 if the part number is purchased exclusively for that customer. Something like this:

```
         Col1  Col2   Col3
0  TUR, Cust1  1001  false
1  GAR, Cust2  1001  false
2  FOR, Cust3  1001  false
3  ERB, Cust1  1002   true
4  PNR, Cust1  1002   true
5  DUL, Cust2  1003  false
6  COC, Cust3  1003  false
7  ETM, Cust1  1004   true
8  ROW, Cust3  1005  false
9  HON, Cust3  1005  false
```

I already tried to extract duplicates with df.duplicated and to evaluate the customer name with str.contains, but without satisfying result. Is there a smart solution that I don't know?
I am new to python and getting nowhere with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the customer from `Col1` then `groupby` part number and count the number of unique customers which should be equal to 1

```
df['Cust'] = df['Col1'].str.split(', ').str[-1]
df['Col3'] = df.groupby('Col2')['Cust'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
```

If only interested in checking the dupes considering one customer at a time, here is a simpler version

```
m = df['Col1'].str.split(', ').str[-1] == 'Cust1' # is cust1?
df['Col3'] = m.groupby(df['Col2']).transform('all') # are all cust1 per part?
```

Result

```
         Col1  Col2   Cust   Col3
0  TUR, Cust1  1001  Cust1  False
1  GAR, Cust2  1001  Cust2  False
2  FOR, Cust3  1001  Cust3  False
3  ERB, Cust1  1002  Cust1   True
4  PNR, Cust1  1002  Cust1   True
5  DUL, Cust2  1003  Cust2  False
6  COC, Cust3  1003  Cust3  False
7  ETM, Cust1  1004  Cust1   True
```

Comment: Thank you, that comes very close. As I understand it, I then have all the part numbers that are purchased exclusively for customers. But I am only interested in one specific customer per query. How do I do that?

Comment: That would be simple just add a boolean `and` condition: `df.groupby('Col2')['Cust'].transform('nunique').eq(1) & df['Cust'].eq('Cust1')`

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I have been looking for hours

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

```
df['Col3'] = df.Col1.str.extract(r',\s(.*)$')[0]
# or: `df['Col1'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1]`

df['Col3'] = df.Col2.map(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Col2','Col3'])\
                         ['Col2'].value_counts().eq(1))

print(df)

         Col1  Col2   Col3
0  TUR, Cust1  1001  False
1  GAR, Cust2  1001  False
2  FOR, Cust3  1001  False
3  ERB, Cust1  1002   True
4  PNR, Cust1  1002   True
5  DUL, Cust2  1003  False
6  COC, Cust3  1003  False
7  ETM, Cust1  1004   True
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the customer names from `Col1` and assign to a new column, `Col3`. (Alternatively, use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).)
- Next, use [`df.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `subset` parameter set to `['Col2','Col3']`. E.g. for a duplicate like `1002, Cust1`, we will keep only the first.
- Now, select `Col2` and apply [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Result at this stage for `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Col2','Col3'])['Col2'].value_counts()` would look as follows:

```
1001    3
1003    2
1002    1
1004    1
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
```

- The values from `Col2` with `1` as the count (i.e. `1002, 1004`) will occur only for one customer, so we can chain [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to get back `True` for these values only, and `False` for the others.
- Finally, we want to place this result inside [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), applied to `Col2` to match the correct booleans. Overwrite `Col3` again with the result.